# More than one request and response calls in datatables

Tags: datatables

"i'm getting more than one request and response calls for a single search" [enter image description here][1]

"[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/neRIg.png"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating your problem.